# Pytorch/Tensorflow: Compute gradient of Mixture of Gaussians log density

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, autograd

I have a mixture of three Gaussians and would like to compute the gradient of the log-density using Pytorch or Tensorflow. How can I do that?

```
from numpy import eye, log
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as MVN

μs   = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2]]              # Means 
Σs   = [eye(2), eye(2), eye(2)]              # Covariance Matrices
cs   = [1 / 3] * 3                           # Mixture coefficients
MVNs = [MVN(μ, Σ) for (μ, Σ) in zip(μs, Σs)] # List of Gaussians

log_density = lambda x: log((sum([c * MVN.pdf(x) for (c, MVN) in zip(cs, MVNs)])))
```

Essentially I would like to compute the gradient of `log_density`. I tried using `autograd.grad` but it fails because of the array assignment.

#### Attempted Pytorch Solution

```
from torch import tensor, eye, sqrt, zeros, log, exp
from torch.distributions import MultivariateNormal as MVN

μs   = [tensor([0, 0]), tensor([2, 0]), tensor([0, 2])] # Means 
Σs   = [eye(2), eye(2), eye(2)]                         # Covariance Matrices
cs   = [1 / 3] * 3                                      # Mixture coefficients
MVNs = [MVN(μ, Σ) for (μ, Σ) in zip(μs, Σs)]            # List of Gaussians

log_density = lambda x: log((sum([c * exp(MVN.log_prob(x)) for (c, MVN) in zip(cs, MVNs)])))
```

#### Attempted Autograd Solution (won't work)

```
from numpy import eye, log, zeros
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as MVN
from autograd import grad

μs   = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2]]              # Means 
Σs   = [eye(2), eye(2), eye(2)]              # Covariance Matrices
cs   = [1 / 3] * 3                           # Mixture coefficients
MVNs = [MVN(μ, Σ) for (μ, Σ) in zip(μs, Σs)] # List of Gaussians

log_density = lambda x: log((sum([c * MVN.pdf(x) for (c, MVN) in zip(cs, MVNs)])))
gradient = grad(log_density)

# If you try using this gradient function you get an error
gradient(zeros(2))
```

The error I get is

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

#### Naive Autograd Solution

There is, of course, a bad Autograd solution that won't scale well. For instance

```
from autograd.numpy import log, eye, zeros, array
from autograd.scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as MVN
from autograd import grad

μs   = [[0, 0], [2, 0], [0, 2]]              # Means 
Σs   = [eye(2), eye(2), eye(2)]              # Covariance Matrices
cs   = [1 / 3] * 3                           # Mixture coefficients

def log_density(x):
    return log((1/3) * MVN.pdf(x, zeros(2), eye(2)) + (1/3) * MVN.pdf(x, array([2, 0]), eye(2)) + (1/3) * MVN.pdf(x, array([0, 2]), eye(2)))
grad(log_density)(zeros(2))  # Works!
```

Comment: What array assignment? Can you show your PyTorch code as well? And the error you get?

Comment: @Albert I suppose the one inside the list comprehension. I have posted my attempted Autograd solution (which doesn't work). I have also posted how I have rewritten the problem using Pytorch

Comment: What's the problem with the pytorch attempt? Did you just stop there?

Comment: @JakobStark yes because I am unsure about what to do. I tried setting `output = log_density(zeros(2))` and then using `output.backward()` but it didn't work. I don't know Pytorch and can't seem to find documentation on simply computing the gradient\jacobian of a function with respect to the input

Comment: I have seen that often people import `Variable` from `torch.autograd` but I am unsure about how to use that

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
from torch import tensor, eye, sqrt, zeros, log, exp
from torch.distributions import MultivariateNormal as MVN

μs   = [tensor([0, 0]), tensor([2, 0]), tensor([0, 2])] # Means 
Σs   = [eye(2), eye(2), eye(2)]                         # Covariance Matrices
cs   = [1 / 3] * 3                                      # Mixture coefficients
MVNs = [MVN(μ, Σ) for (μ, Σ) in zip(μs, Σs)]            # List of Gaussians

x = tensor((0.0,0.0), requires_grad=True)
log_density = log((sum([c * exp(MVN.log_prob(x)) for (c, MVN) in zip(cs, MVNs)])))

log_density.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

which will print the gradient at (0.0,0.0). However as pytorch is not generating a static computation graph, I could not find an easy way to calculate the gradient at another point without rebuilding the computation graph. You could try to use tensorflow, which gives you more control on the computation graphs and allows you to construct a graph for the gradient computation.

**Edit** With tensorflow you could do something like

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

@tf.function
def mygrad(x):
    print("building graph")
    us   = tf.stack([tf.constant([0.0, 0.0]), tf.constant([2., 0.]), tf.constant([0., 2.])])
    covs = tf.stack([tf.eye(2), tf.eye(2), tf.eye(2)])
    cs   = tf.constant([1 / 3] * 3)

    with tf.GradientTape() as gt:
        gt.watch(x)
        log_density = tf.math.log(tf.math.reduce_sum(tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalTriL(us,covs).prob(x) * cs) )

    return gt.gradient(log_density,x)

print(mygrad(tf.constant([0.0,0.0])).numpy()) #gradient at 0.0,0.0
print(mygrad(tf.constant([1.0,0.0])).numpy()) #gradient at 1.0,0.0
```

Essentially you do automatic differentiation with the `tf.GradientTape` and capture the computation graph in a `tf.function`. There is more background information on the very extensive [Tensorflow API documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/all_symbols).

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to help me with tensorflow please?

Comment: I added a paragraph with a tensorflow solution